# Improve response time query on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I would like to ask you if you have any idea here on how to improve the performance on this query.
I thought maybe partitioning could help on table1(id) but its not. I created index on table1(id) but also it didn't help much. Do you have another idea on how to improve the performance in this type query?

```
SELECT a.source,
    a.id,
    .
    .
    .

    b.speed
FROM schema.table1 a
   LEFT JOIN schema.view b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.field::text ~~ '15%'::text
      AND b.field::text >= ((SELECT field
                         FROM schema.view1))
   OR b.field::text ~~ '16%'::text
      AND b.field::text >= ((SELECT field
                             FROM schema.view1))
   OR b.field::text ~~ '4%'::text
      AND b.field::text >= ((SELECT field
                             FROM schema.view1));
```

Comment: Could you share the query plan, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, COSTS, BUFFERS) for this statement?

Comment: The query is malformed. The outer join is silentlty converted into an inner join.

Comment: @TheImpaler What do you mean by that?

Comment: The filter `b.field::text ~~ '15%'::text` forces `b.field` to be not null. So, in practice essentially the `LEFT JOIN` will work as a plain `JOIN`. There's no effective outer join in the query.

Comment: The formatting of your query seems more designed to confuse than to clarify.

Comment: Seems that you filter on a view `schema.view`. How is this view defined ? From which table does the column `b.field` come from ?

Comment: @Edouard It comes from ```schema.view b```